# Unable to get highlighting working on TextEdit

Tags: qt, qml, syntax-highlighting

TL;DR: `TextEdit` paints highlighted text only when I click on it. Nothing helps

I have a `ListView` with a `QAbstractListModel` model with string properties.
Those string properties are being spellchecked and `QSyntaxHighlighter` is used to show spell errors. I create `QSyntaxHighlighter` descendant in `Component.onCompleted` of `TextEdit`. I double-checked highlighting get's executed with correct spell errors and `setFormat()` of Highlighter is executed with correct positions. The problem is that it draws text in red (invalidates) only when I click on the `TextEdit` itself.

`TextEdit` lives in a `Flickable` (to track cursor) and `Flickable` lives in a `Rectangle` (to have nice background and border). Binding to some signals and calling update() of `TextEdit` does not help.

After spellcheck finishes, I emit `rehighlight()` signal of created SyntaxHighlighter.

```
Rectangle {
  id: descriptionRect
  height: 30
  border.width: descriptionTextInput.activeFocus ? 1 : 0
  clip: true

  Flickable {
      id: descriptionFlick
      contentWidth: descriptionTextInput.paintedWidth
      contentHeight: descriptionTextInput.paintedHeight
      anchors.fill: parent
      interactive: false
      flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick
      height: 30
      clip: true
      focus: false

      function ensureVisible(r) {
          if (contentX >= r.x)
              contentX = r.x;
          else if (contentX+width <= r.x+r.width)
              contentX = r.x+r.width-width;
      }

      TextEdit {
          id: descriptionTextInput
          width: descriptionFlick.width
          height: descriptionFlick.height
          text: description
          onTextChanged: model.editdescription = text

          Component.onCompleted: {
              globalModel.initDescriptionHighlighting(index, descriptionTextInput.textDocument)
          }

          onCursorRectangleChanged: descriptionFlick.ensureVisible(cursorRectangle)
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is a small sample of project with demonstration of how it does not work until you click on a text https://bitbucket.org/ribtoks/qt-highlighting-issue

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: I built and executed your source but the program works as you expected.  the words are highlighted right after I clicked the check spelling button.  I used Qt 5.5.1 on OSX

Comment: Everything works as you expected, try rebuild project with make disclean && qmake && make'

Comment: It doesn't work for Qt 5.4 for sure. With or without cleaning and qmaking. It may be working on 5.5.1. But I need to keep a compatability in my product up to Qt 5.2, which would need some hack as well as 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just encountered this issue on 5.11.2 and found the following fix which allows updating of individual blocks without having to highlight/deselect the whole text area

```
rehighlightBlock(newBlock);
Q_EMIT document()->documentLayout()->updateBlock(newBlock);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for this update. Have you tried patching small codefile in the example? (to confirm it works)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was probably caused by [QTBUG-44765](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44765), fixed in Qt 5.5.

<strike>Given the low level of the bug, I don't think it is practically to work around it.</strike>

You can work around that by appending an empty string to the TextEdit when you're done with the syntax highlighting

```
TextEdit {
    id: captionTextEdit
    width: wrapperFlick.width
    height: wrapperFlick.height
    text: display
    readOnly: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        itemsModel.initHighlighter(index, captionTextEdit.textDocument)
    }

    Connections {
        target: itemsModel
        onUpdateTextEdit: {
            console.log("Update element at index: " + indexToUpdate)

            if (indexToUpdate == index)
            {
                console.log("Update me!")
                captionTextEdit.append("")
            }
        }
    }

    onCursorRectangleChanged: wrapperFlick.ensureVisible(cursorRectangle)
}
```

where `updateTextEdit(indexToUpdate)` is a new signal your itemsModel has to emit.

itemsmodel.h

```
signals:
    void updateTextEdit(int indexToUpdate);
```

itemsmodel.cpp

```
void ItemsModel::initHighlighter(int index, QQuickTextDocument *document) {
    // Signal mapper could be avoided if lamda slot are available (Qt5 and C++11)
    QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    if (0 <= index && index < m_ItemsList.length()) {
        SingleItem *item = m_ItemsList.at(index);
        SpellCheckHighlighter *highlighter = new SpellCheckHighlighter(document->textDocument(), item);
        QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(spellCheckResultsReady()),
                         highlighter, SLOT(rehighlight()));

        // TODO: Don't connect this slot for Qt 5.5+ to avoid performance overhead
        QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(spellCheckResultsReady()),
                         signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
        signalMapper->setMapping(item, index);
    }

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),
            this, SIGNAL(updateTextEdit(int)));
}
```

Full code is available here: https://bitbucket.org/swarta/rehighlighdemo/branch/workaround#diff

Comment: Hi Simon. I end up with the same workaround. Just not using `append("")`, but using method `deselect()` instead. Actually, I'm using Qt 5.5.1 and in my complicated app this still doesn't work (requires workaround) while for demo it works in 5.5.1. Anyway, I still didn't bothered to answering this question with my approach so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Okay cool. So we have a good solution for other people finding and upvoting this. Your demo project provides a lot of value for everyone who wants to get started with syntax highlighting in QML, so it would be nice to keep it alive.